# Docker from running container "bash:docker:command not found"

Tags: docker

I am trying to run docker commands from inside my container, but I always get the response "bash: docker: command not found".  I've built my image successfully, and run it by trying the following two ways: `docker run -it ubuntu bash` and `docker run -it ubuntu`.  All is good running the image, however when I try to execute a shell script by doing the following: `docker exec ubuntu /path/to/script.sh`, I receive the "command not found" error.  Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:focal
WORKDIR /home/mark/Downloads/docker
ENV TZ=America/New_York
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt update && apt -y upgrade
RUN apt -y install software-properties-common wget
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:cybermax-dexter/mingw-w64-backport
RUN wget -qO - https://packages.lunarg.com/lunarg-signing-key-pub.asc | apt-key add -
RUN wget -qO /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lunarg-vulkan-1.3.204-focal.list https://packages.lunarg.com/vulkan/1.3.204/lunarg-vulkan-1.3.204-focal.list
RUN apt update && apt -y upgrade
RUN apt -y install build-essential mingw-w64 gcc-11-multilib g++-11-multilib nano sudo vulkan-sdk
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-11 90 && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-11 90
RUN update-alternatives --set x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix
RUN update-alternatives --set x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix
RUN update-alternatives --set i686-w64-mingw32-gcc /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix
RUN update-alternatives --set i686-w64-mingw32-g++ /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN wget -qO - https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_20.04/Release.key | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c "echo 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_20.04/ ./' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/OBS_WineHQ.list"
RUN sed -i 's/# deb-src/deb-src/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y build-dep wine
RUN apt -y install libusb-1.0-0-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev:i386 libgcrypt20-dev libx11-dev libx11-dev:i386 libfreetype-dev libfreetype-dev:i386 samba-dev
RUN apt -y install libxpresent-dev libxpresent-dev:i386 libxi-dev:i386 libxcursor-dev:i386 libxxf86vm-dev:i386 libxinerama-dev:i386 libxcomposite-dev:i386 
RUN apt -y install libosmesa6-dev:i386 ocl-icd-opencl-dev:i386 libpcap0.8-dev:i386 libdbus-1-dev:i386 libgnutls28-dev:i386 libsane-dev:i386 libgphoto2-dev:i386
RUN apt -y install libpulse-dev:i386 libgstreamer1.0-dev:i386 libudev-dev:i386 libsdl2-dev:i386 libcups2-dev:i386 libv4l-dev:i386 libfontconfig1-dev:i386
RUN apt -y install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev:i386 libkrb5-dev:i386 libopenal-dev:i386 libvulkan-dev:i386 libldap2-dev:i386 libcapi20-dev:i386
```

The docker docs say what I am doing should work.  What gives?

Comment: You can't run `docker` commands from inside the container, unless (a) you install the `docker` CLI tool in your Dockerfile and (b) you publish the Docker socket into the container when you run it, giving the container unrestricted root-level access over the entire host.  Have you done both of these things?  Can you [edit] the question to provide a [mcve]; on the one hand showing the exact `docker build` and `docker run` commands you're running, on the other removing all of the `RUN` commands that aren't necessary to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Actually, I haven't done either of those things.  The docker build is the latest Linux build as of two days ago, and the run commands were posted exactly as I entered them.  I have a hunch this will solve my issue.  If it doesn't, I'll edit the post with the needed details.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm diving deep now, and your answer may not be all there is to it.  Still digging...

Comment: This should be all that's needed to have access to `docker` commands:
`docker run -t -i -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /path/to/static-docker-binary:/usr/bin/docker busybox sh`.  Unverified, but it comes straight from the docs.  I managed to solve my issue by educating myself some.

Comment: Bind-mounting the host's binary isn't reliable (if it's a dynamically-linked binary from your Linux distro, `busybox` can't run it) and it's better to install it in your Dockerfile if you can.

Comment: But, to reiterate the security concerns, you can `docker run --rm -v /:/host -u root busybox vi /host/etc/shadow` to reset the host's root password to whatever you want, and otherwise make arbitrary edits to the host filesystem: think really carefully before you make Docker-socket access part of your setup.

Comment: Thanks.  I just saw that command in the docs, but wasn't aware of security vulnerabilities.  The authors didn't mention them.  Either way, I found a safe way to do what I wanted to do, and learned in the process.

Answer (score 0):

I has this issue fixed by running the following command by sharing host machine's docker.sock to container.

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock /tail -f
/dev/null
```

I also had to ssh to the container and installed docker as well

```
docker exec -it 8cd4cb427637 /bin/bash 
apt-get update ; 
apt-get install docker.io -y
docker ps
```

and I was able to see list of running containers from host machine.